# Line end of this 4-way circuit?

Tags: electrical

Which of these three switches in this 4-way circuit is the line end?  I want to install a dimmer and from what I understand, it should be on the LINE end.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What make/model dimmer is it, and can we have views into the backs of the respective boxes?

Comment: It’s not the 3rd picture.  Use a non-contact voltage tester and figure out which black stays hot from the first two pictures all the time, regardless of load/light on or off.

Comment: Yes, put a voltage tester on the black screw and throw the switch, if it's always on, that is the line wire.   If you plan to change any switches, mark both traveler wires with yellow electrical tape (or any color).  The travelers are the wires on the brass screws of 3-ways, and all the wires on 4-ways.  They can both be the same color because there is no need to distinguish them from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Oh fun: I had to do this when I upgraded to a multi-location dimmer system!

It's not the third picture: that's a four-way switch.

If it's wired correctly, you just have to disconnect the black wire from the "Common" terminal on each of the three-way switches and then use a current detector to see which one is hot: that's your line!

Safest way, and to remove all doubt in case the circuit is wired "unconventionally":

1. Shut off power to the circuit.
2. Tag (so you can reconnect the same way) each black wire connecting to the three-way switches.
3. Disconnect the black wires from the three-way switches.
4. Restore power to the circuit.
5. Use current detector to find the hot black.  That's the line source for the circuit!

(If none of those four shows hot, test the red wires still connected to each three-way to find the line source.  And in that case don't recommend whomever wired it the first time ;)